# What happened to Twilio.Message class in the Twilio library for c# 5.x?

Tags: c#, twilio

In the old Twilio Helper library, there is Twilio.Message that represents the Twilio SMS message instance. I am wondering what happened to it in the C# 5.x library? Is it changed to MessageResouce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

Yes, `Create` is a factory that returns a new MessageResource object.

```
MessageResource msg = MessageResource.Create(
            from: new PhoneNumber("555-555-5555"),
            to: new PhoneNumber(person.Key),
            body: $"Hey {person.Value} Monkey Party at 6PM. Bring Bananas!");
```

Hope that helps.